# Using public transportation in Malta to see as much of Malta (towns, villages, landmarks, etc.) as possible in a logical & systematic way?

Tags: public-transport, buses, landmarks, malta

I shall be visiting Malta for two weeks this summer and shall be staying in Mellieha, located in the north of the island, close to the ferry terminal where one can travel to its sister island - Gozo. Using only the local bus network as well as visiting the capital Valletta I would like to see as much of Malta (towns, villages, landmarks,  places of interest etc....) as possible **in a logical & systematic way**. As Malta is one of the smallest nations in Europe (hopefully) this should be fairly achievable.

Any guidance on using the bus service on Malta (& Gozo) in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: as per my other comment on the answer, I've edited this question to be about a single thing - the transportation, and recommend you ask a separate question on places of interest, making sure to check the guidelines in the [faq] first.

Comment: Mellieha is a wonderful spot and, around the town, there are many picturesque places that one can reach even walking (my fav: [Blata il-Bajda](https://goo.gl/maps/mSpVkYYMQB7HusWP9)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is feasible without any problem. Malta has a very dense bus network, operated by [Malta Public Transport](https://www.publictransport.com.mt/). It provides the usual local connections, airport transfers and in some places even night buses. It's straightforward to use. You can use the [journey planner](https://www.publictransport.com.mt/en/trip-planner), to get an idea of the available options.

The price of a single ticket is €2.50 during the day and €3.00 at night, and [there are discounts for day tickets or 7 day tickets](https://www.publictransport.com.mt/en/bus-card-and-ticketing). Having a car is not so practical, it can even be cumbersome.

Gozo can be easily reached [by ferry](https://www.gozochannel.com/). The price for a single trip is €4.65. Malta Public Transport also operates a bus network on Gozo.

Comment: +1 for the bus network operator, however I would like to know more about what places of interest, landmarks, monuments, museums (if any) etc is worth visiting & where they are located, and how easy they are to get to whilst travelling on the bus network.

Comment: I seem to remember that the bus network on Gozo is less than ideal.

Comment: @MasterBaba I think Gozo is such a small place you can just get on one of those open top sightseeing red buses, when you get off the ferry at Gozo port and it will show you Gozo in a few hours. I'm more concerned with Malta, what there is too see there & how to get to those places, on the local buses.

Comment: What there is to see is well covered by travel guides. The list can be long. Travel guides also explain you how to get to the different places. If you have doubts about how to get to one specific place, ask  that as a separate question

Comment: @MarcelC. I thought maybe someone might have knowledge of Malta & could advise on various things to see, (or that are worth seeing). Its a small island, I'm sure the list cannot be that exhaustive (i'm sure somethings might be seasonal). I have seen other questions posted here where people have asked "What to see when visiting X", the answers provided have been quite detailed. I couldnt find any questions relating to Malta here so I thought it would an appropriate one to ask.

Comment: @Simon you're asking two questions here - using local transportation, and about places of interest.  I'd split them off - edit this one to be just the local transportation, and then make a new one for places of interest.  However, please read the [faq] on how to word such a question - just asking for what places to see and so on violate the [faq] as it's asking for a list of recommendations.

Comment: Apparently, the url is now http://www.publictransport.com.mt/

Comment: Single trip from Gozo to Malta. From Malta to Gozo the ferry is free.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzeved true, you only pay the way back from Gozo to Malta.